# How do you save user input in a list in the actual Python3 script file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, save

I'm trying to make a script that lets me input whether an inventory count was correct or not and return the percentage of correct inventories. I would like to save the user input from the terminal in a list so that all I have to do is run the script again and the input is still there from previous entries.

so basically,

```
list = []
userInput = input('Y or N')

if userInput == 'y':
    list.append('y')
else:
    list.append('n')
```

But keep the input saved to the list after the script finishes running

Comment: This is what files & databases are for.

Comment: Once the script finishes, the variables are lost.  You need to externally store them in a .csv, .txt, file or more commonly some database.  If you never used one before, I'd recommended downloading MySQL and finding a tutorial.  You will need to learn how to make a table, how to insert into a table, update, and delete from a table to begin with.